# MySQL Count 2 values from same field

Tags: mysql, count

How can I count two different values from the same field? I have a field called Jobs and I'd like to count how many Doctors and how many Policemen in the same query.

This is my query which counts both but returns them in the same result. I'd like to separate this result. Here is my query:

```
USE DBAssignmentPartC;
SELECT Cu_City as City, Count(Cu_Job) AS TotalPoliceDoctors FROM tblCustomers
WHERE Cu_Job = 'Doctor' OR Cu_Job = 'Policeman'
Group by Cu_City ORDER BY TotalPoliceDoctors DESC;
```

Is it possible to still count BOTH Doctor's and Policemen and return them in their separate columns?

I have tried searching on here and on Google but as a first year student I may be searching/using the wrong terms and I apologize if this has been answered and I've missed it.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your `Count(Cu_Job)` to `SUM(Cu_Job="Doctor") , SUM(cu_job ="Policeman")`

```
SELECT 
    Cu_City as City, 
    SUM(Cu_Job = "Doctor") as totalDoctors , 
    SUM(Cu_Job = "Policeman") AS totalPolice, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Cu_Job = "Doctor" OR Cu_Job = "Policeman" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPoliceDoctors 
FROM tblCustomers
GROUP BY Cu_City 
ORDER BY TotalPoliceDoctors DESC;
```

this returns by city the count of each doctor and the count of each policeman as well as the total count

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab1ad4/1)

NOTE:
just so you know how this is working (so you can explain it to your professor incase you need to) `SUM(Cu_Job = "Doctor")` returns a boolean value meaning for each row `Cu_Job = "Doctor"` will either be true or false. MySQL (as well as basically all other programming languages) treats a true as 1 and a false as 0. so summing up the 'true' values will give you a COUNT of the specific value inside a column.

Comment: @JamieSutton sure thing! does it make sense?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes it kinda does...what does the THEN 1 ELSE 0 END mean? Thanks for your help wish I could give you +1 but can't!

Comment: @JamieSutton the THEN ELSE END are all parts of MySQL's CASE statement.. its a logic thing. `CASE WHEN my_condition THEN something ELSE something` similar to an IF statement.. so I have a statement saying if the row is either a doctor or policeman then enter in a 1 to be summed for a total count or else put in a 0 since we dont want to count others. and thanks for the offer! if you get enough rep feel free to come back and trow me one :) I went ahead and gave you a +1 on your question!

Answer (score 0):

try this. You should be getting two rows for each city, one for policeman one for doctor with count

```
USE DBAssignmentPartC;
SELECT Cu_City as City, Count(Cu_Job) AS count FROM tblCustomers
WHERE Cu_Job = 'Doctor' OR Cu_Job = 'Policeman'
Group by Cu_City, Cu_Job ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried this but unfortunately the results are still in the same column.

Comment: @JamieSutton my bad, should be count cu_job instead of *. How about now